Resolution of the singularity of a lemniscate
The equation $(x^2+y^2)^2-x^2+y^2=0$ defines a lemniscate. Let $f(x,y)$ denote the LHS.
My question is:
Is there three-variable polynomials $g(x,y,z)$ , $h(x,y,z)$ that satisfies below?

The equation $g(x,y,z)=h(x,y,z)=0$ defines a non-singular space curve.

The projection of the zero set of that curve on xy-plane is  the zero set of $f(x,y)$. i.e. $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2; \exists z\in\mathbb{R}. g(x,y,z)=h(x,y,z)=0\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;f(x,y)=0\}$.


I know basic calculus and linear algebra.
What I tried:


A single equation such as $g(x,y,z)=0$ defines a surface typically, not a curve as your attempted figure suggests. So I don’t understand what you really want here.

@Pranay I misunderstood it. I will edit the question.

Welcome to MSE!
The usual way to resolve a singularity like this is to blow up the intersection point (which, for us, is the origin).
We do this by noticing that while the curve intersects itself, the slopes of the two intersecting segments are different. So we'll plot the curve in 3D, using the slope of the line as the $z$ coordinate.
Concretely, that means we want $\frac{y}{x} = z$, or in polynomials, $y = zx$. Making this substitution we get
$$
(x^2 + z^2x^2)^2 - x^2 + z^2 x^2 = 0
$$
which simplifies to
$$x^2 (1+z^2)^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0$$
and we can plot this surface:

This looks strange at first, until we remember we're only supposed to be considering the $y$ coordinates for which $z$ really is the slope! That is, we want to intersect this with the surface $y=zx$:

If we draw the intersection of these two surfaces, we get...

which, seen from above (read: projecting out the $z$ coordinate) should look familiar!

You can play around more in this desmos file. Note that I used a parameterization of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ that isn't rational, just for convenience of plotting. The curve itself is defined in terms of polynomials as the intersection of $x^2 (1+z^2)^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0$ and $y=zx$.

I hope this helps ^_^
